# Почему некорретно работает класс AutoResetEvent?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Необходимо основной поток ставить в режим ожидания, пока не вызовется событие окончания таймера.
Но почему-то всё срабатывает сразу, не дожидаясь окончания таймера. И лишь после начинает выводиться в консоль события TimerCallback пачками по 10.

```
class Program
{
    public static AutoResetEvent objAuto = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static Timer timer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyApp();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Событие окончания таймера");

        objAuto.Set();
    }

    private static void MyApp()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Запускаем таймер на 5 сек");

            timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 5000);

            Console.WriteLine("Ожидаем таймер");

            objAuto.WaitOne();

            Console.WriteLine("Переходим к следующему таймеру");
        }
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неверно используете [таймер](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Timer__ctor_System_Threading_TimerCallback_System_Object_System_UInt32_System_UInt32_)

Вы указываете параметр `dueTime` как `0`, отчего событие таймера вызывается незамедлительно.

> `dueTime UInt32`
> Количество времени до начала использования параметра callback, в миллисекундах. Следует задать поле Infinite для того, чтобы не допустить запуск таймера. Задайте значение ноль (0) для немедленного запуска таймера.

Comment: Всё, я понял, теперь всё правильно работает, спасибо большое!